# Undefined reference to `pthread` after compiling Qt C++ code with aarch64-linux-gnu-g++

Tags: c++, qt, g++, arm64

I have a simple Qt C++ code as follow:

```
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QString test="HELLO WORLD!";
    qDebug()<<test;
    return 0;
}
```

I can compile this file with g++ in Ubuntu by this command in terminal:

```
g++ -fPIC -I"/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/gcc_64/include/" -I"/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore" -L"/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/gcc_64/lib"  main.cpp -lQt5Core -o output
```

But when I want to compile the above file with aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ for arm64:

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ -I"/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/include" -I"/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/include/QtCore" -L"/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/" -L"/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib" main.cpp -lpthread -lQt5Core -o output
```

I get these errors:

```
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libz.so, needed by /home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libc++_shared.so, needed by /home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: liblog.so, needed by /home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libc.so, needed by /home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete@LIBC'
/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `geteuid@LIBC'
/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `pthread_self@LIBC'
/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `rename@LIBC'
/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `pthread_key_create@LIBC'
/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `prctl@LIBC'
/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `munmap@LIBC'
/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_destroy@LIBC'
/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `access@LIBC'
/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `readlink@LIBC'
/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `strerror_r@LIBC'
/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `ftruncate@LIBC'
/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `unsetenv@LIBC'
/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `write@LIBC'
/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `sysconf@LIBC'
/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `dlopen@LIBC'
/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `setsid@LIBC'
/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `strlen@LIBC'
/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `strrchr@LIBC'
/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `fwrite@LIBC'
...
/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `strerror@LIBC'
/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `free@LIBC'
/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `fstat@LIBC'
/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `pthread_condattr_destroy@LIBC'
/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `setenv@LIBC'
/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `printf@LIBC'
/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to `execve@LIBC'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I think adding -lpthread should solve these undefined reference errors but it can not. How can I solve that?

Comment: Sounds like you're not linking a needed dependency.

Comment: Linkers can be quite 'fussy' when it comes to the ordering of libraries on the command line.  Try changing `-lpthread -lQt5Core` to `-lQt5Core -lpthread ` and moving it to *after* `-o output` to see if that changes anything.

Comment: @Chipster thanks, so what is the needed dependency?

Comment: @G.M. thanks, I execute `aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ -I"/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/include" -I"/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/include/QtCore" -L"/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/" -L"/home/***/Qt5.12.7/5.12.7/android_arm64_v8a/lib" main.cpp -o output -lQt5Core -lpthread` but the same errors appear.

Comment: Not exactly sure. I'm going to guess the ones in the first 4 lines of the output. But I'm not too familiar with qt to be completely sure. That's just my guess. Have you tried using -rpath or -rpath-link like it suggested?

Comment: @Chipster no I have not tried that because I have used absolute path.